# Swift cancellation of NSOperationQueue does not work

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to cancel `NSOperationQueue` process using method `cancelAllOperations()` using swift but it does not work.

I am downloading a file from `url` when i cancel the download it doesn't work.

here is the code i am using:

```
var s = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()

lazy var session : NSURLSession = {
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
    config.allowsCellularAccess = false
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: self.s)
    return session



    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)  //set progressBar to 0 at start

       }

@IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {

    s.cancelAllOperations()

}


func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten writ: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite exp: Int64) {
    print("downloaded \(100*writ/exp)")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.counter = Float(100*writ/exp)
        return
    })
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didResumeAtOffset fileOffset: Int64, expectedTotalBytes: Int64) {
    // unused in this example
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
    print("completed: error: \(error)")

    if(error != nil){

    }

}

// this is the only required NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate method

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {


    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
    let fileManager = NSFileManager()
    let destinationURLForFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingString("Music.mp3"))

    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destinationURLForFile.path!){  
        print("File Already Exists")
    }
    else{

        do {

            try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(location, toURL: destinationURLForFile)

            print("File doesn't exists")
        }catch{
            print("An error occurred while moving file to destination url")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your implementation of `cancel` look like in your operations? Look at the documentation of `cancelAllOperations()`; you still have to do some work to handle the call in your operations.

Comment: i am trying to cancel the download progress...

Comment: I know what you're trying to do - I'm asking what you've done to support what you want to do.

Comment: I tried using task.cancel() to cancel the download progress,the download has been cancelled but the problem is it doesn't start the download again upon clicking on download button.i don't know where the problem is i  am new to iOS development.